# Getting a FileNotFoundException in VSCode, but not in JGrasp

Tags: filenotfoundexception

Ok, so this is what's going on. I'm trying to learn how to use vscode (switching over from jgrasp). I'm trying to run this old school assignment that requires the use of outside .txt files. The .txt files, as well as other classes that I have written are in the same folder and everything. When I try to run this program in JGrasp, it works fine. Though, in VSCode, I get an exception. Not sure what is going wrong here. Thanks Here is an example:

[image]

[image]

```
import java.io.*;

public class HangmanMain  {
    public static final String DICTIONARY_FILE = "dictionary.txt";
    public static final boolean SHOW_COUNT = true;  // show # of choices left

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the cse143 hangman game.");
        System.out.println();

        // open the dictionary file and read dictionary into an ArrayList
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(DICTIONARY_FILE));
        List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            dictionary.add(input.next().toLowerCase());
        }

        // set basic parameters
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What length word do you want to use? ");
        int length = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How many wrong answers allowed? ");
        int max = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

//The rest of the program is not shown. This was included just so you guys could see a little bit of it.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a project, jGRASP makes the working directory for your program the same one that contains the source file. You are creating the file with a relative path, so it is assumed to be in the working directory. You can print new File(DICTIONARY_FILE).getAbsolutePath() to see where VSCode is looking (probably a separate "classes" directory) and move your data file there, or use an absolute path.